# What is the best way to implement a pseudo-random number generator in C++ that supports querying the nth random number for a given seed?

Tags: c++, random, range-v3

My use case is that I am doing something akin to generative art that involves lazy range-v3 range views containing randomly generated geometric primitives.

I am limited by the fact that for certain operations, when iterating over the aggregate range view, the computation performed by the range views' iteration implementation requires accessing the same random number twice. These numbers are ultimately coming from `ranges::views::generate` returning numbers generated by `std::mt19937`. When the `generate` happens twice it will return different numbers.

One way around this problem would be to do basically the following instead of using `views::generate`:

```
ranges::views::iota(0) | 
ranges::views::transform([](int n){return nth_random_number(n, some_rnd_engine);}
```

my question is is it possible to implement `nth_random_number(i, some_rnd_engine)` on top of anything in the standard library, or otherwise. Note that the above is just pseudocode in the actual code I need the separation between engine and distribution, etc., as in the standard library.

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21460748/1413244) that a linear congruential engine should be able to do this, and indeed [there is one in the standard library](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/linear_congruential_engine/), but I believe there is no standard way to access its internal state in a rich enough way to implement the feature I want.

Comment: There's nothing like that in the C++ library. This sounds like an XY problem, with X being unclear.

Comment: You may have better success with hash functions, for the use case of converting strings to random-behaving numbers.

Comment: yeah hashing would work but then trouble is I have to write my own code for generating normally distributed values.

Comment: Concerning the `std::linear_congruential_engine` algorithm, it is effectively possible to modify it such that we can get the k^th value in O(log k)` time. Not clear if it will solve all your issues.

Comment: std::linear_congruential_engine is so simple that seeding it should be trivial in terms of time efficiency right? I could write a wrapper around it that just forwards min(), max(), and seed() to std::linear_congruential_engine but for operator() hash the current seed with an additional index variable that can be set externally, set the seed, and then call operator() on the wrapped linear_congruential_engine.

Comment: @jwezorek You may want to look into using a [counter-based PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-based_random_number_generator_(CBRNG)), which makes this problem trivial to solve. A commonly used PRNG of this type is [Philox](http://www7.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p2075r1.pdf). To the best of my knowledge, the C++ library does not offer a counter-based PRNG yet.

Comment: @njuffa thanks ... counter-based PRNGs are what i am looking for. there is an implementation of philox et. al. from that paper here https://github.com/johnsalmon/cpp-counter-based-engine
in which if you look at the example code it is doing things similar to what i am talking about in this question

Comment: @jwezorek A very simple counter-based PRNG that may or may not be suitable for your purposes can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.06278). Your question is specifically about support via the C++ standard library, and while Philox has been *proposed* for inclusion, it has not made it into the ISO standard yet, best I know.

Comment: yes i will change the wording of the question so that it affords a more interesting answer than "no".

Comment: You could use the [MRG32k3a](https://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/doc/node267.html) generator. It was designed by Pierre L'Ecuyer and passes statistical tests such as BigCrush successfully. The cost of moving its state N steps forward is like k*log(N); this is because that boils down to small matrix exponentiation with elements in Galois fields, and we can use the [Indian exponentiation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). MRG32k3a has been proposed for inclusion into the C++ standard, but these wheels tend to move slowly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible, but it will be horribly slow.
It would involve resetting the generator back to the start with the **same seed** (probably by recreating it over each time) then calling `discard` to advance the generator by n.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine/discard

You could also do it for a generator that doesn't have discard by simply calling the generator N times.

Comment: i should have mentioned in the question that the queries need to be O(1) time, or at least O(log n)